# Extensions of sheaves with isomorphic middle terms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, coherent-sheaves

Let $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ be two coherent sheaves on a variety $X/k$. If I know that $\dim_k \operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G})=1$, and I have two different nontrivial (not splitting) extensions 
$$
0 \to \mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{F} \to 0,
$$
and 
$$
0 \to \mathcal{G} \to \mathcal{E'} \to \mathcal{F} \to 0,
$$
could I conclude that $\mathcal{E} \cong \mathcal{E'}$? Is it true if I additionally assume that $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are line bundles?

Comment: Do you assume that these extensions do not split ?

Comment: Yes, sure, these are two nontrivial extensions. I need to add this to the post.

Comment: Have you seen the stanard proof that $Ext^1$ classifies extensions? Or do you wish for a direct proof?

Comment: I know that proof, it is not what I'm asking. Ext^1 classifies extensions up to isomorphism of extensions, my two extensions are not isomorphic as extensions, but I hope that middle terms of extensions are isomorphic in this situation. Isomorphism of middle terms does not necessarily fit into an isomorphism of extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's true.

Suppose the first extension corresponds to an element $\xi\in\operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G})$. Then if $\lambda\in k$, the extension corresponding to $\lambda\xi$ can be constructed by taking the pullback along the map $\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{F}$ given by multiplication by $\lambda$. But since, if $\lambda\neq0$, this is an isomorphism, the resulting extension will be isomorphic, as a short exact sequence, to the original one.